# Allow displaybreak only from even to odd pages

Tags: displaybreak

I am using the command `\allowdisplaybreaks` for continuing equations from page to page. I think that breaking equations from an odd to an even page is not very "efficient" because we haven't a view on all the equation in this case. So I want to make this command allowing break only from even to odd page. Anyone have an idea about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some limitations caused by TeX output routine, but in typical situations it should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\textheight4cm %short pages, to see the result
\begin{document}



\makeatletter
\everymath{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\allowdisplaybreaks[0]%
    \else \allowdisplaybreaks[4]%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
Some text

\begin{align*} %an example of action
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}




\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine on your example and on my (long) documents. It was what I wanted... Thks... What's the limitations you talk about ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna in general tex doesn't know what page the text is on at the point that the test is made, so in some cases the "wrong" value may be chosen (although if no page break happens anyway that may not matter) think of a simple case where a long align spans more than one page, the same setting true or false is used for both page breaks....

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna In some  cases it may happen, that the value of the counter is changed, because TeX have just made the next try to split a text into pages. But it should be so rare, that it is better to manually change something in such a case, than to use the mechanism of writing to auxilary files and reading information from them.

Comment: Ok. I understand the problem. Thank you for your pedagogic explanation for you two

Comment: Hello @David and @Przemyslaw. I recall you after all this time because of this problem: I use this macro in a book environment and after adding the command \frontmatter and when I compile I obtain the message 
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.
 <to be read again> 
                    i
 l.25 \end{align}
                 
 A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
 (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
 look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

what's the cause of this problem ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna better to ask a new question rather than comment on an old one. I would guess you have redefined  `\thepage` not to be a number, it should anyway be `\value{page}` I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Perhaps '\thepage' is redefined by the command \frontpage !?

Comment: Would you see please this new question opened. Thanks

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268865/allowdisplaybreaks-and-frontmatter

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for the solution I haven't understand well yesterday