# \allowdisplaybreaks and \frontmatter

Tags: amsmath

Based on this discussion,

[Allow displaybreak only from even to odd pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224020/allow-displaybreak-only-from-even-to-odd-pages/224031?noredirect=1#comment645119_224031)

I use the macro

```
\makeatletter
\everymath{%
  \ifodd\thepage\allowdisplaybreaks[0]%
    \else \allowdisplaybreaks[4]%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

to allow breaking page in equations only from even to odd pages. 
When I use the command `\frontmatter` in the beginning of the file, I've the following compilation error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.25 \end{align*}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

What's the cause of this message and how can I treat this problem ?

N.B.1: I have this error' message but the file compiles well...

N.B.2: This error' message is caused by the command `\frontmatter`... i.e. there's no error if the command `\frontmatter` doesn't exist

Here's the file `.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\textheight4cm %short pages, to see the result
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\everymath{%
  \ifodd\thepage\allowdisplaybreaks[0]%
    \else \allowdisplaybreaks[4]%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\frontmatter
Some text

\begin{align*} %an example of action
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\thepage` in `frontmatter` is in roman format while `\ifodd` expects a number (in arabic format i.e., 1,2,3 etc). You should use `\value{page}` instead of `\thepage` in

```
\makeatletter
\everymath{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\allowdisplaybreaks[0]%
    \else \allowdisplaybreaks[4]%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\textheight4cm %short pages, to see the result
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\everymath{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\allowdisplaybreaks[0]%
    \else \allowdisplaybreaks[4]%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\frontmatter
Some text

\begin{align*} %an example of action
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & b\\
c& d\\
e& f\\
g &h
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works well. Thanks for solution and explanation